# Unplug headphones to get audio from speakers

Tags: sound, 18.04, headphones, speakers, audio-jack

i need to unplug the headphones in order to get the audio from the speakers even   they are both connected.

[image: Screenshot of my Settings]

if both speakers and headphones are connected i only get the option to output audio from the headphones and if i unplug the headphones i only get the option to output audio from the speakers

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking here,what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to have both listed on the sound tab so i can choose what device to output audio from like in windows